# ADT plugin does not show up in ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I started using Ubuntu recently and I'm trying to get Eclipse installed. I followed the online instruction for adding the ADT plugin on Eclipse, but after adding the name and the URL, nothing happens, I'm supposed to get a plugin and then click next and install it according to the website, but I don't see any plugins there!! o.O

Answer (score 0):

In some countries this webpage is banned. Maybe this is your case. If it is you need to download ADT and install it manually.